# Confusing in event Form_Load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form-load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Luanching.... This may take a few second");
............
    }
```

Here if I don't click OK in messagebox my from will not show up
(It will wait until me click)
how to fix this
how to make form show up first or how to make doesn't wait for click OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to place a backgroundworker on the form. Then in the events, doubleclik on 'DoWork' in the method that is then created in code, place the messagebox.show.
This way the messagebox is shown in a separate thread and the loading of the form will continue

Comment: not to speak of. I have a program that utilizes about 25 separate threads at one time and each thread has only a couple of kb's of memory (this was a thread pool). It is what you do inside the tread that potentially causes memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, Just move the MessageBox code to `Shown` event

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Luanching.... This may take a few second");
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a valid reason don't vote it down!

Comment: Indeed Sriram Sakthivel. you answer is a perfectly fine option for the problem.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil I have no idea which numpty has voted down :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I am not the downvoter, but may be having it in `Shown` event kills the purpose of message. `Form_Load` may take 2 minutes during which the user should be be able to see this message. With your code, The user will see the message after `Form_Load` has completed its work

Comment: @Habib You're absolutely correct. I just answered the question *how to fix this how to make form show up first ?*. Answer depends upon question only. If OP asked how to speed up form load or something like that my answer'd be to move the cpu intensive code to another thread or use a "Splash screen"

Comment: I have used backgroundworker but I still want to know event shown? I never see it in property is this event have to be create by myself?

Comment: Form exposes `Shown` event which will be called after `Load` event. Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `MessageBox`, you have to create a new `Form` which shows a message. 
New `Form` will run on a new message loop, so will not block ui, if call it like

`myForm.Show()` , where `myForm` is your form's instance.

Answer (score 0):

The event `Form1_Load` is exaclty what it sounds, so if you insert some sort of `MessageBox` there, the `Form` will only load *after* the response.

Consider using another method, after the `Form` load.